# How are we supposed to help if the author keeps removing the question?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Related question**
>
> [How do i make sense out of asp key decrypted ninja3 xml *(deleted)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162848/how-do-i-make-sense-out-of-asp-key-decrypted-ninja3-xml)

This is probably not a very good question, but the last few days various 1 rep users have posted a question about decrypting an XML file that has something to do with Classic ASP but the format is not something I've heard of or managed to find on the web. 
This interested me but the minute I asked questions to try and ascertain what they are trying to do and whether I can help they voluntarily remove the question??

It's very frustrating and I don't know of anyway through SO I can contact the user to encourage them to un-delete it.

Sorry not really a question more of an observation, just wondered if anyone has any thoughts on it.

Comment: Ech. That question should stay deleted, and the user too.

Comment: Guess the encryption questions are really not a good fit for Stack Overflow, certainly not when the OP has not put in any effort to make sense of it themselves.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I guess so the question wasn't posed very well but the subject was one I wanted to help or understand better and maybe improve the question for other users benefit.

Comment: You may not have seen it before the question was deleted, but the user's last comment demonstrates that they aren't mature enough to be a Stack Overflow member. Pretty clearly. If you like the question, you might post it, or something like it, yourself.

Comment: if user persists in this kind behavior, eventually system will help them by [question blocking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta No didn't see it. Oh well guess some people can't be helped.

Comment: FWIW the name of the user who deleted it is extremely offensive in Swedish.

Comment: I've seen users before who ask a question and then delete it when it is answered in the comments, or when they solve it themselves. This behaviour generally should be met with re-education, though I get that doesn't apply here if it is intended to be deliberately disruptive.

Comment: Could the user possibly been already encouraged to delete by the question having already been closed, downvoted, or comments posted suggesting that it was a poor fit for the site? If it had been closed already then your attempt to answer it would have been frustrated either way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the account information, and their repeated offensive behavior, I suspect this user is a troll. We destroyed this account for a reason.

If they keep creating new accounts and posting this, flag the posts and let us know about them. They do this enough and the system will eventually block them.

Comment: Oh right will do.

Comment: @Brad Larson I have asked several questions but some of them were not up to the standards And lots of users who has this authority to "down vote question"simply down votes it without explaining,I wasn't aware of this standard of asking a question so,I decided to delete them and thats what I did, but after facing the same for 2 to three times I realized (someone mentioned it) that this is the issue, but by the time I realized this thing, I have already lost my privilege of asking more questions.Can you please tell me how these new users(like me) are suppose to understand these things ?

Comment: @Abhinay Read the help centre before posting, and if a question is heavily downvoted with no comments and you really don't understand why, ask here for help understanding where you went wrong and how you can improve future questions.

Comment: @Abhinay: the issue here is slightly different, as the user is _deliberately_ posting bad questions. But yes, as Michelle says, you can ask a question on Meta if you don't understand downvotes you've received.

Comment: @Michelle: He just did..

Comment: @Michelle: They just asked here for help understanding where they went wrong and how they can improve future questions. Your answer to this was "ask here for help understanding where you went wrong and how you can improve future questions"!!

Comment: @Michelle: `|   x   |` <-- read x

Comment: Could y'all have this discussion somewhere else? None of it is related to the question here.